# Retrieving a sequential documents based on _id

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I've got a scenario where documents are indexed in elastic search, and I need to retrieve the matched document in mongo along with the preceding and following documents as sorted by a timestamp. The idea being to retrieve the context of the document along with the original document.

I am able to do this successfully now if I use a sequential _id. As an example, using the following data:

```
[
    {_id: 1, value: 'Example One' },
    {_id: 2, value: 'Example Two' },
    {_id: 3, value: 'Example Three' },
    {_id: 4, value: 'Example Four' },
    {_id: 5, value: 'Example Five' },
    {_id: 6, value: 'Example Six' },
    ...
]
```

if I search for 'Four' in ES, I get back the document _id of 4, since it's sequential I can create a mongo query to pull a range  between id - 2 and id + 2, in this case 2 - 6. This works well, as long as I do not ever delete documents. When I delete a document I'll have to re-index the entire series to eliminate the gap. I'm looking for a way of achieving the same results, but also being able to delete documents without having to update all of the documents.

I'm open to using other technologies to achieve this, I am not necessarily tied to mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

I can get the desired results using something like the following:

```
collection.find( {_id: { $gte: matchedId } } ).limit(3);
collection.find( {_id: { $lt: matchedId } } ).sort({$natural: -1}).limit(2);
```

Not quite as nice as using an explicit range, but no need to recalculate anything on document deletion.

Yes, I am aware of the [limitations of natural order](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sorting+and+Natural+Order), and it is not a problem for my particular use case.

Comment: One caution on natural order: unless you have a capped collection, the natural order over time will not match the "preceding/following" documents as you expect.  In particular, document deletion and moves will create gaps in available data space where documents can be inserted or moved to.  If you are expecting a certain order (such as insertion order) you should use an explicit indexed sort() instead.  In your example, you'd want to sort on the `_id` field.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has nothing to do with MongoDB in particular and is not different from using a different database here (e.g. a RDBMS). You will have to loop for document ids smaller/larger than the current id and find the first two matching. Yes, this means that you need to perform multiple queries. The only other option is to implement a chained list on top of MongoDB where you store pointers to the right and left neighbour node. And yes, in case of a deletion you need to adjust pointers (basic datastructure algorithms....). The downside is: you will need multiple operations in order to perform the changes. Since MongoDB is not transaction you may run into inconsistent previous/next pointers....that's why MongoDB completely sucks here.

Comment: There are other ways to solve the problem when using RDBMS. Using SQL Server for instance, I could use a CTE with ROW_NUMBER. I may be able to get what I'm looking for using a map reduce function. I'll have to look into that.